# exported variable to be used on remote server

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I am exporting a variable on my host, such as:

```
export TOPICS="A B C"
```

Then, I'd like to use the TOPICS variable on a remote machine via ssh, like:

```
ssh user@remoteHost <<EOF
  for word in $TOPICS; do
  ./modify.sh $word
  done
exit
EOF
```

It appears once I ssh onto the remote host the value in TOPICS can no longer be seen. Is there a way to export the variable via the ssh command? I tried putting single quotes around EOF, as well as before < < EOF and after EOF, but neither worked.

Comment: `$TOPICS` is being used. Unless you put quotes around `EOF`, variables in the here-doc are expanded locally. The problem is `$word`. This gets expanded locally, but it's being set remotely.

Comment: Should single quotes around the second occurance of EOF theoretically fix the problem with $word?

Comment: If you use `<<'EOF'` it will fix `$word`, but break `$TOPICS`.

Comment: Cool... so how can I fix both?

Comment: Put a script on the remote host that does what you want, and then do `ssh user@remotehost "./scriptname $TOPICS"`.

Comment: Or put a backslash `\ ` in front of `$word`

Comment: Using the \ seems to be the best solution, thank you both for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

By adding the '\' n front of $word the script executes correctly, thanks @Adrian Pronk